# how to hide nav bar on first view only

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

How can i make it so the nav bar is hidden on the first view only, i have some code that will let me do it but if i go to my second view then back to my first i can see the nav bar slide up is there any way to make it so it doesnt do that. here is the code i have.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first view

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

In second View

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
{
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just have an instance variable and keep track of whether it's the first time the view is appeared, ie. `BOOL isFirstTime` make sure to set it to `YES` in your `viewDidLoad` and pass it to `setNavigationBarHidden:` in `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    isFirstTime = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:isFirstTime animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    isFirstTime = NO;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldHideNavBar;

@end


@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:self.shouldHideNavBar animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.shouldHideNavBar = YES;
}

@end
```

The first run though, the default value for shouldHideNavBar is NO. After viewWillAppear gets called for the first time, it is set to YES. So, next time viewWillAppear is called, your nav bar will be hidden.